# Can a light fixture that uses three bulbs be changed out for one that uses one bulb, using the same wiring?

Tags: wiring

I have two outside light fixtures by the garage that use three 60 watt flame shaped bulbs. I am wanting to change the fixtures out for ones that use just one regular 60 watt bulb. Will the same wiring work for the new one-bulb fixtures?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's fine. In normal US residential installation, the wiring for lighting is rated for a minimum of 15A. 3 x 60W = 180W = 1.5A @ 120V. Of course, going to a smaller fixture would never be a problem anyway, but the point is you could also increase without a problem, up to a maximum of 1,500W (which would be a **lot** of light).

However, I urge you to *not* install any fixture using 60W bulbs. Install LEDs. You can either figure out what to get based on *lumens* - a typical 60W incandescent bulb generates around 800 lumens of light, or look for the made-up number "60W equivalent". A typical LED "60W equivalent" bulb might use 9W of power.

There are also LED fixtures with integrated LEDs instead of removable bulbs. Given the long lifespan of decent LEDs, a fixture with integrated LEDs often makes a lot of sense, especially for outdoor fixtures.